# JsonObject dimension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic

I have a simple problem with jsonObject dimension.
I need to create a dynamic table that will add number of row equals to the record that are in the jsonObject.
My code is as follow:

```
    var jsonObject = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

    var count=Object.keys(jsonObject).length;
    alert('count2 equal'+count);
```

When I execute it, count values is 2.
This is the content of jsonObject in the servlet:

```
{
"type" : "perso_atti",
"values" : [{
        "CF" : "hygt45rfd56tgyui",
        "costo_orario" : 20,
        "cup" : "1",
        "data" : "2015-01-07",
        "id_Attivita" : 1,
        "numeroOre" : 4
    }, {
        "CF" : "hygt45rfd56tgyui",
        "costo_orario" : 20,
        "cup" : "1",
        "data" : "2015-01-12",
        "id_Attivita" : 1,
        "numeroOre" : 4
    }
    ....
```

I don't understand why the value is 2.
I have 30 record so it may be 30.

Comment: If you are using `Object.keys()` you surely can use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`

Comment: If you are saying that `values` contains 30 elements and you want that number, then you have to read the length of `values`, not the outer object. If you are unfamiliar with `Object.keys` please read the MDN documentation first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var count = Object.keys(jsonObject).length` is 2 because there are only 2 keys: `type` and `values`. I believe what you want is

```
var count = Object.keys(jsonObject.values).length;
```

Or you can just do `var count = jsonObject.values.length` as @FelixKling suggests.

Comment: Seems like `jsonObject.values.length` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @FelixKling absolutely.